# Normal text outside the graph container of cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

How is it possible to have selectable text or clickable hyperlinks on the same HTML page as a cytoscape graph? In all the examples, the title (h1 tag text) is not selectable. Is it somehow possible to a a div container "outside" the graph area, where text is selectable and link can be clicked?

Comment: just put the div after cy canvas. Also z-index matters

Comment: Yes, thanks! I just realized the issue is the the CSS that I adopted from the demo. It's set to position-absolute at 0/0, which is just overlapping everything. As a simple solution, I moved it some 50 pixel down, so I can have interactable text above it. But this doesn't work well on mobile, so I better play with the z-index!

Answer (score 0):

As [suggested by canbax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70221881/normal-text-outside-the-graph-container-of-cytoscape-js/70628592#comment124174374_70221881), putting the content div after the cy div and setting the z-index of the cy div to 0 solved the issue! At least the first element in this div stays selectable.